# asp.net core mvc 6 No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7168/Event/DeletePost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core

I don't understand why I don't get data when started DeletePost action method I got date in Delete method but don't get in DeletePost can somebody explain?

```cs
//Get - Delete
public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
{
    if (id == null || id == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var obj = _db.Event.Find(id);
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(obj);
}

//Post - Delete
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult DeletePost(int? id)
{
    var obj = _db.Event.Find(id);

    if (obj == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    _db.Event.Remove(obj);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Here is the Delete View where i send Request to DeletePost, Dont dont if it help some how. But mby it helping some how. i get post method and get asp-action
Delete View

```
<form method="post" asp-action="DeletePost">
    <input asp-for="Event_ID" hidden />
    <div class="border p-3">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <h2 class="text-info pl-3">Delete Event</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Event_Title"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Event_Title" disabled class="form-control" />
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Event_Description"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Event_Description" disabled class="form-control" />

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Event_ShortDesc"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Event_ShortDesc" disabled class="form-control" />

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-8 offset-4 row">

                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger w-100" value="Delete" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success w-100"><i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i>&nbsp;Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                @* Keep this empty *@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Can you show how you post the request to `DeletePost` Action?

Comment: You thing how i get it in View?

Comment: Add name attribute in input element. `<input asp-for="Event_ID" name="id" hidden />`

Comment: @YongShun Ty it work, but can you explain, why I need use it now, in last project it work all whit out attribute name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `asp-for="Event_ID"`, it will render the `<input>` HTML element as

```
<input id="Event_ID" name="Event_ID" hidden />
```

When submitting the form, it will submit the `Event_ID` value as `Event_ID` parameter.

But your Action expects the `id` parameter.

```cs
public IActionResult DeletePost(int? id)
```

So you need to overwrite the `name` attribute by providing it in the `<input>` element. Thus, this will pass the `EVENT_ID` value as `id` parameter.

```
<input asp-for="Event_ID" name="id" hidden />
```

Reference: [The Input Tag Helper](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/input-tag-helper)